# Showing a youtube video with fancyBox, scroll is enabled in chrome only

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I am using version 2.1.5 of the [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin to show a Youtube video in a popup - similar to how the jQuery lightbox plugin functions, only with video media.

This works flawlessly in IE, Firefox and Opera but when testing against Chrome, the video loads up in the overlay fine however it allows you to scroll the iframe up and down the page, the overlay also doesn't appear to cover the whole height of the page. A screenshot is included below to demonstrate:

[image]

As you can see, the overlay doesn't cover the whole page and the iframe is allowed to be scroll vertically. This isn't an issue in other browsers and appears to be a chrome only problem. Has anybody come across this before?

My JS + includes are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link href="/Css/fancy.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            helpers: {
              media: {}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the markup:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://youtu.be/Ut7Hrc26TAI">
    <img src="/Images/laptop-find-out-more.png" alt="Find out more" />
</a>
```

I am using jQuery version `1.8.2` min. I have tested this with newer versions of jQuery to no avail.

How can I prevent this scrolling behaviour and ensure that the overlay covers the entire page in chrome?

Comment: It works fine for me. Just check out the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvsca/1/.

Comment: Do you have a mousewheel?

Comment: Sure!! But the example in the official page has the same functionality (the background is scroll-able and the black overlay is 'cutted'). So it's a plugin issue, not yours. Check it out here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples - YouTube link under Media helper tab.

Comment: Yep, seems that way. Ah well, looks like I'm sticking with my workaround for now :)

Comment: Yep. By the way, try to always check an 'official' examples of the plugin before starting to use it.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan I did, the official example is where I got the default implementation from.

Comment: So, why you didn't check the result too? :)

Comment: I didn't need to see it working, I only needed the basic code. Besides, it's broken on their site for me too anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to hook into the `afterShown` and `afterClose` callbacks and manually disable the scroll as there doesn't appear to be an official fix for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            afterShow: shown,
            afterClose: closed,
            helpers: {
                media: {}
            }
        });
    });

    function shown() {
        $('html, body').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'height': '100%'
        });
    }

    function closed() {
        $('html, body').css({
            'overflow': 'auto',
            'height': 'auto'
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the same situation.

Comment: You might want to get the current setting of overflow and height and assign them to a variable before you set the overflow and height... That way you can re-assign it after and the page will behave as before.